# How to read a Excel file and convert it to JSON Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, excel, visualization

I have an excel file with multiple sheets in it. I want to read the sheets one by one and store the data in each sheet in JSON Arrays where each array contains data in one sheet.

Can someone please help me out here? Is there any JavaScript library to do this?

Each sheet has three columns and I want to store the data from these columns in JSON Array.

Comment: Do you need to do the conversion once? Or programatically?

Comment: Programatically. I want to write the code to first convert the individual sheets in excel file into JSON Array and then will be using that JSON Array for further operations.

Comment: Is the user uploading the excel files? Or are the excel files stored on your server?

Comment: There is one excel file with multiple sheets in it, present on my local machine and I am only using it from my local machine itself.

Comment: If it's an `*.xslx` file, then you just need an unzipper and an XML parser, both of which should be easy to find. XLSX is just a renamed Zip of XML files.

Comment: Is there any way to do this using jQuery. For example, reading the excel file and then directly row by row storing the data in JSON Array?